# Parsing sentences in Haskell more effectively using attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I'm trying to parse an ebook in .txt form, to learn more about attoparsec and Haskell (I'm a newbie). In this case, I'm trying to count the number of sentences in the given text file. Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Txt
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative ((<*>), (*>), (<$>), (<|>), pure)

data Prose = Prose {
  word :: [Char]
} deriving Show

optional :: Parser a -> Parser ()
optional p = option () (try p *> pure ())

specialChars = ['-', '_', '…', '“', '”', '\"', '\'', '’', '@', '#', '$',
                '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '~', '`', '{', '}',
                '[', ']', '/', ':', ';', ',']

inputSentence :: Parser Prose
inputSentence = Prose <$> many1' (letter <|> digit <|> space <|> satisfy (inClass specialChars))

sentenceSeparator :: Parser ()
sentenceSeparator = many1 (space <|> satisfy (inClass ".?!")) >> pure ()

sentenceParser :: String -> [Prose]
sentenceParser str = case parseOnly wp (T.pack str) of
    Left err -> error err
    Right x -> x
    where
        wp = optional sentenceSeparator *> inputSentence `sepBy1` sentenceSeparator

main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- readFile "test.txt"
  let sentences = sentenceParser input
  print sentences
  print $ length sentences
```

Click this [link](https://github.com/ceekyay/HaskellParser/blob/master/Main.hs) to the github repo if you want to take a complete look at what I'm doing. 
My problem is that when I try to parse text file with input: [image]

I get an`output as follows:

[image]

So my question is, how can I:

1. Make the parser realize that anything with "\n\n.." is a different sentence.
2. Input like `Daniel G. Brinton` is just 1 sentence.

I've tried using `isHorizontalSpace`, but to no avail.

Comment: According to your question 1, the sentence separator should rather be "at least two newline characters", e.g. `endOfLine >> many1 endOfLine`

Comment: @ceeks can you change the images for actual text? It would make it easier to help you out.